# Remove part of a string in a dataframe column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Col1     Col2       Col3  
1     1998-09-02     A  
2     2011-10-29     B  
3     2000-12-24     C  
4     2008-09-12     D  
5     2004-07-09     E  
6     2013-01-31     F
```

And I want to make Col2 into year instead of the exact dates, something like:

```
Col1    Col2     Col3  
1       1998      A  
2       2011      B  
3       2000      C  
4       2008      D  
5       2004      E  
6       2013      F
```

At the same time, I want the strings in Col2 be integers so that I can subset my dataframe for later programming.
How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

More a question for stackoverflow.com.

Try this

```
# using only base R:
as.integer(format(format="%Y", as.Date( "1998-09-02")))
# returns 1998 for example
# gets the month 
 as.integer(format(format="%m", as.Date( "1998-09-02")))

library(lubridate) # on CRAN

# convert to Date datatype with lubridate
dfr$Col2     <- year( as.Date(dfr$Col2))
dfr$Col2_mon <- month(as.Date(dfr$Col2))  # lubridate
```